# Where is my minecraft folder in files explorer, Windows 10?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

Using windows 10,1.16.40  and i cant find my folder in file explorer.  Have tried to use WIN+R and typing in %appdata% and all that kinda stuff. Hidden files is on. Tried different c combinations of folders (such as: Microsoft, windows etc ) still zero luck.

Comment: Try this path in your file explorer: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft. You can swap "Users" for your actual user

Comment: Are you playing minecraft java edition or minecraft bedrock edition?

Answer (score 1):

Something you might've not tried is finding the folder manually. Go to "This pc">(drive windows is installed on)> "Users">(your user), Now make sure that in the "view" tab in explorer, that "hidden items" checkbox is checked. A folder named "App data" should appear, and it's translucent. Open it, then the folder named "roaming" then you should find .minecraft there. If it isn't there, then you somehow messed up the Minecraft installation.

Comment: I wouldn't say "messed up the Minecraft installation", but rather changed the directory/path of the Minecraft folder.

Comment: @snoopstick It doesn't matter where you put your directory, that's where the main game files are. There always will be a .minecraft folder in Roaming which is where you install mads, shaderpacks, and where worlds and screenshots get saved. The only exception is if you installed Minecraft through a third party Minecraft launcher tool like multi-MC.

Comment: oh I get it now